# > operator in Python gives different results while using integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print the greatest number here.

Python version 3.4.2. Also tried in 3.5.0.

```
a = input("A...")
b = input("B...")
if a>b:
    print(a)
else:
    print(b)
```

Results:

> ```
> A...5
> B...43
> ```
>
> 5

========= RESTART =========

> ```
> A...4
> B...44
> ```
>
> 44

========= RESTART =========

> ```
> A...5
> B...44
> ```
>
> 5

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers. Python 3's `input()` returns strings.

Comment: You don't have integers, you have strings.

Comment: convert these strings to integers before comparing `a = int(a); b = int(b)`

Comment: that helped! thank you all